# Laravel оптимизация кода

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, telegram-bot, php-fpm

Создал телеграм бот на Laravel 5.8

**Сервер:** 
nginx + php-fpm (directadmin)
32gb, 500gb SSD, 12 x 2.20GHz.
PHP 7.1
MySQL 5.7.27

ДБ не большая, бот новый и пользователей тоже не так много. 
За час в пик приходит 30 тысяч запросов и бот уже конкретно лагает.

Все дб запросы проходят по индексу, но кэш не использовал пока, так как это демо версия еще. Особо тяжелого кода не использовал. Я раньше никогда столько запросов не отправил через php. Поэтому подозреваю что это все из-за ответных запросов на бот от моего сервера. В данный момент запросы идут не в отдельном потоке. Использую обычную команду **Request** **longman/telegram-bot** для запросов.

Ларавел начал изучать недавно. Подключил листенер для ДБ запросов

```
    DB::listen(function ($query) {

        if ($query->time > 100) {
            //лог
        }
    });
```

за пик в лог самый медленный запрос попал этот (их было всего 15):

```
update `table` set `night` = night+1, `current_type` = ?, `status` = ? where `id` = ?
```

Время выполнения: 2738.99 (миллисекунд)
Как видите update идет по ID.
команда **top** показывал почти 100 процентную нагрузку на все потоки.

Общий скрипт выше 6000 строк кода. один cron который запускается каждые 2 секунды

```
for i in {0..30}; do curl http://URL/ && sleep 1; done;
```

Что посоветуете для оптимизации? и как можно найти какая именно часть кода нуждается в оптимизации? Слишком подозрительная нагрузка для такого мизерного количества запросов. 
Стоит ли выводит ответные запросы на отдельный цикл и обработать там ? если да каким образом лучше делать?

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 100
pm.process_idle_timeout = 20
pm.max_requests = 500
```

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить конкретный такой запрос, поставив `EXPLAIN` впереди. Понятно что "по айди", но мало ли)  Насколько оптимизирована БД? Попробуйте `mysqltuner`. С `pm = ondemand` процессы будут уничтожаться и форкаться в зависимости от трафика. В принципе лучше использовать static, ведь RAM и CPU не меняются)  Посмотрите настройку "PHP-FPM slow log" чтобы дампить медленные скрипты.

Comment: EXPLAIN сразу же попробовал. но в phpmyadmin он выполнялся за 0.00х секунд. То есть ничего подозрительного. Что-то происходит, резко производительность падает и в результате так получается. Как-то можно следить за пхп ? думаю не в дб проблема

Comment: See [here](https://robertbasic.com/blog/php-fpm-slow-log/) + NGINX Amplify (чтобы видеть что происходит лучше). Особенно смотреть swap usage. См. также `dmesg` (может процессы падают)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону загрузки памяти php процессами. Можно смотреть пиковые нагрузки скрипта через функцию memory_get_peak_usage. 8 запросов в секунду при выполнении запроса в бд длительностью 3сек довольно быстро замусорят память, особенно если таймаут 20сек и лимит запросов 500, возможно бд так долго иногда отвечает потому что php процессы стоят в очереди и едят всю память. Опять таки если делаются какие то операции с файловой системой в скрипте. Слишком много идей можно придумать если не видеть метрики и код